# how can i pass a 2 word parameter to another page without getting %20 between the words

Tags: php, redirect

I'm using this header location:

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
header ("Location: http://www.oldURLL.com/results.php?" . $q . "");
```

When `q` is

```
q=word1 word2 or q=word1+word2
```

the destination becomes

```
q=word1%20word2
```

How can I make it stay as it was in the original URL with the space or plus sign?

Comment: You might want to use urlencode/decode functions: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php . That should also provide you with some degree of security.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is this causing a problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can use an ampersand (&) to unify the parameters.

```
example.php=param1=aasdasd&param2=qweqwe
```

In your example this would be:

```
header ("Location: http://www.oldURLL.com/results.php?param1=".$q."&param2=".$q2);
```

Comment: I am not sure if this will work with `q=word1 word2` or q=`word1+word2`